# How to get users current title using sphttp (Not sp.web or pnp) spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api

Can someone give me the code to get the current logged in user for a spfx webpart. I don't want pnp.sp or sp.web please, I want to use spHttpClient etc.

I cannot find the basic code ANYWHERE on the internet. A link will do.

Regards,

T

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse,ISPHttpClientOptions} from '@microsoft/sp-http';    
this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties`,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) =>{
        response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => { 
          console.log(responseJSON.DisplayName)
         })
      })
```

Comment: Getting an error of 0: Unable to get property 'get' of undefined or null reference

Comment: null object reference, try to debug which object is null. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/debug-in-vscode